# Find the greatest common divisor of $f(x)=2x^3+2x^2+x+4$ and $g(x)=x^4+3x^3+4x^2+3x$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Find the greatest common divisor of $f(x)=2x^3+2x^2+x+4$ and $g(x)=x^4+3x^3+4x^2+3x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$

[image]

Comment: I think the gcd is equal to one.

Comment: You should avoid writing fractions in a finite field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to perform the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) modulo $11$:
$$\begin{align}
h_1(x)&:=g(x)+(5x-1)f(x)\equiv 7x^2+7,\\
h_2(x)&:=f(x)+(6x+6)h_1(x)\equiv -x+2,\\
h_3(x)&:=h_1(x)+(7x+3)h_2(x)\equiv 2.\\
\end{align}$$ Hence, in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$,
$$\gcd(g(x),f(x))=\gcd(h_1(x),f(x))=\gcd(h_1(x),h_2(x))=\gcd(h_3(x),h_2(x))=1.$$

Comment: @RobertZ..............gcd =1?

Comment: Yes. Have you understood the procedure? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You need to work in $$\mathbb{Z}_{11}[x]$$ where those fractions change to integers.

For example  $(1/2)  =6$ because  $2\times 6 =1 $ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$

Also you need to continue the process further to get the g.c.d